# 2011 Community Moderator Election - Town Hall Chat:  10pm UTC / 6pm EDT on the 16th

Tags: discussion, election

In connection with the moderator elections, I am looking to set up a Town Hall Chat session with the candidates.  This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary.  I am working with the candidates to find a time that allows the most participation.

**The Town Hall Chat will take place Thursday the 16th at 10pm UTC / 6pm EDT.**

[**view in other timezones**](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/fixedtime.html?month=6&day=16&year=2011&hour=22&min=0&sec=0&p1=0)

[register here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/556/math-town-hall-chat?tab=schedule)

Here are the details so far:

- I have coordinated with the candidates and done the best I could with a best fit match. <s>I would like to schedule this towards the beginning of the election phase, so I am looking at the 15th-18th.  As soon as I coordinate with the existing moderators and candidates, I will edit this post with details on the "when".  (Hopefully I'll hear back quickly so we can get this scheduled on short notice.)</s>
- The Town Hall Chat will be a one-hour event using our [chat platform](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=math.stackexchange.com).  You can register for the chat here.
- The format will be an open discussion.  Users are encouraged to pose questions to the candidate regarding their thoughts on moderation.
- After the chat session, the transcript of the event will be permanently linked here.

Comment: Waiting to see if I get the last 2 responses today...looking like Thursday early evening US east/central.

Comment: @JonasMeyer, not anymore - thanks!

Comment: @All: I would like to wish everyone lots of luck in the chat. As some of you know, I am currently detained away from my computer and the internet, so I will not be able to make it there. But I will attempt to make it towards a computer again in the next few days, and so if anyone would like to ask me anything please feel free to email me at david.j.lowry()gmail.com

Comment: Can we see a transcript somewhere?